# Mantener estado de un Fragment

Tags: android-studio

**EDITADO DESPUES DE LA RESPUESTA.**

Tengo una actividad con dos botones, cada uno realiza un cambio de fragmento de la siguiente manera.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        OneButtom.setOnClickListener{
            openfragment(OneFragment())
        }

        TwoButtom.setOnClickListener{
            openfragment(TwoFragment())
        }
        
    }

    fun openfragment (fragment:Fragment){
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Dentro de los fragmentos tengo un Webview, funciona bien el problema es que cuando, se cambiar de fragmento la pagina del Webview se vuelve a recargar, yo deseo que la pagina se quede como estaba cuando se cambio de fragmento, por ejemplo en el lugar que estaba el scroll y la ultima pagina que se cargo.

He intentado de diferentes maneras, pero ninguna me funciona.

FRAGMENT ONE

```
class OneFragment: Fragment(R.layout.fragment_one) {

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        OneWeb.saveState(outState)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        OneWeb.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient(){

        }
        OneWeb.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient(){
        }

        val setting: WebSettings = OneWeb.settings
        setting.javaScriptEnabled = true

        savedInstanceState?.let {
            OneWeb.restoreState(it)
        } ?: OneWeb.loadUrl("https://youtube.com")

    }
```

FRAGMENT TWO

```
class TwoFragment: Fragment(R.layout.fragment_two) {


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        TwoWeb.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView, progress: Int) {
                if (progress == 100) savedInstanceState?.getInt("scroll")?.let {
                    view.scrollTo(0, it)
                }
            }
        }
        TwoWeb.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient(){

        }
        val url = savedInstanceState?.getString("url") ?: "https://youtube.com"
        TwoWeb.loadUrl(url)

        val setting: WebSettings = TwoWeb.settings
        setting.javaScriptEnabled = true
        TwoWeb.loadUrl("https://google.com")

    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        outState.run {
            putString("url", TwoWeb.url)
            putInt("scroll", TwoWeb.scrollY)
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

}
```

También he probado [este proyecto](https://github.com/mbove77/WebView-SaveState/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bove/martin/bairesdevchallenge/fragments/GoogleFragment.kt) donde se implementa con éxito lo que explico, pero al implementarlo no me funciona.

Comment: Dentro de que método realizas la transacción del Fragment?

Comment: Ya, lo agregue; esa es una implementación  que vi en un tutorial, pensaba que iba a funcionar  ya que también he intentado con la nueva [Navegacion que implemento android ](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started), pero tampoco se puede.

Comment: Si es por que la implementación no lo permite, agradecería sus ideas de una forma diferente de hacerlo.

Comment: Hay un par de cosas que están mal pero lo peor es que tus 2 fragments son iguales! Estás violando uno de los principios básicos de la programación que es "don't repeat yourself". Si lo que quieres es cambiar de página al presionar un botón, puedes hacerlo en el mismo webView. En el proyecto que mencionas está guardando el estado con `saveState` y `restoreState` como en mi respuesta con la diferencia de que crea su propio bundle en lugar de usar el predeterminado.

Comment: Aparte de eso, estás creando un nuevo fragment cada vez que tocas un botón en lugar de utilizar los que ya creaste. En el proyecto que citas tienes un ejemplo de como hacerlo correctamente. Además en el segundo fragment llamas `loadUrl()` 2 veces seguidas. Entonces cómo esperas ver los efectos de la primera llamada? Intenta entender lo que hace tu código, no sólo copies y pegues.

Comment: Con sus ultimas indicaciones, pude entender mejor lo que estaba pasando y solucionar los errores, me sirvió mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te estás enfocando en el lugar equivocado, tu problema no tiene que ver con la navegación.
En lugar de intentar mantener el fragment siempre en memoria, deberías dejarlo seguir su ciclo de vida y almacenar en un bundle los elementos que quieras restaurar. Debes tener en cuenta que las otras maneras de guardar un estado no funcionan cuando tu app es cerrada por el sistema.

Para guardar un estado debes sobrescribir el método `onSaveInstanceState` de tu fragment

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    OneWeb.saveState(outState)
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

Luego reemplaza `OneWeb.loadUrl("https://youtube.com")` por esto:

```
savedInstanceState?.let {
    OneWeb.restoreState(it)
} ?: OneWeb.loadUrl("https://youtube.com")
```

> Please note that this method no longer stores the display data for this WebView. The previous behavior could potentially leak files if restoreState(Bundle) was never called.

Cómo dice su descripción, los métodos `saveState` y `restoreState` del webView no guardan todo el estado y tal vez ni siquera necesites usarlos. De todos modos creo que este es el enfoque más apropiado, identificar exactamente qué necesitas restaurar y guardarlo en el bundle. Por ejemplo si sólo necesitas la url y el scroll puedes hacer esto:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    outState.run {
        putString("url", OneWeb.url)
        putInt("scroll", OneWeb.scrollY)
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

y lo restauras así:

```
OneWeb.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
    override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView, progress: Int) {
        if (progress == 100) savedInstanceState?.getInt("scroll")?.let {
            view.scrollTo(0, it)
        }
    }
}
val url = savedInstanceState?.getString("url") ?: "https://youtube.com"
OneWeb.loadUrl(url)
```

Si quieres saber más, puedes leer la documentación sobre como guardar estados:

- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states
- https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state
- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#save-simple,-lightweight-ui-state-using-onsaveinstancestate

Pero sobre todo te recomiendo leer [esto](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#bottom_navigation) para que evites ese boilerplate que estás usando para navegar.